# BIOS keep switching OS support option from "others" to "Windows 8 64-bit" in advanced tab, preventing w7 to start. How can I fix that?

Tags: windows, windows-7, bios

I have this BIOS that keep switching OS support option from "others" to "Windows 8 64-bit" in advanced tab, preventing windows 7 to start even albeit I did save & exit the settings when exiting the BIOS. How can I fix that? that behavior changes back as soon I start windows again, it isn't anew update or anything. How can I fix that?

edit: BIOS info:

```
version: 1.01W
EC version: 1.06.53
Manfacturer name: digibras
Product Name: NH4CU53
```

Comment: Have you disabled Secure Boot?  All OEM devices that came with Windows 8.0+ are required per Microsoft to allow Secure Boot to be disabled.  Since you have an OEM device (more than likely) then Secure Boot can be disabled.

Comment: @Ramhound I can disable it and I did it but it also switch back in the same way as OS support change from "others" to "windows 8 64-bit" it's not saving the changes I've made for some reason

Comment: Changes are not saved - sound like a CMOS battery is low.

Comment: @Hardoman I was thinking the same, I'll buy a new one and replace to see if it does fix the issue